# Googe drive api - no support for map export (python)

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Using the python api client I can export google docs using `export` or `export_media` and non-google doc material with `get_media`.

Maps saved in the user account are unexportable.  `export` returns the error

`HttpError: <HttpError 403 ... returned "Export only supports Google Docs.">`

I admit it makes no sense to use `get_media` but I try anyway given the above error. It returns:

`HttpError: <HttpError 403 ... returned "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Google Docs files.">`

It seems `get_media` and `export` disagree about what this object is.

I suggest that `export` should work with `mimeType='application/vnd.google-earth.kmz'`

Comment: Have you tried using the `webContentLink` to get the file (looks like this https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/uc?id=FILE_ID&export=download)?

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot, It seems that wbContentLink is only available for [binary content](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource).  I think the `get_media` method is a wrapper for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Drive.About.get` to determine the export formats available for each Google MIME type:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?fields=exportFormats&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "exportFormats": {
  "application/vnd.google-apps.form": [
   "application/zip"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.document": [
   "application/rtf",
   "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
   "text/html",
   "application/pdf",
   "application/zip",
   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
   "text/plain"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.drawing": [
   "image/svg+xml",
   "image/png",
   "application/pdf",
   "image/jpeg"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet": [
   "text/csv",
   "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
   "application/zip",
   "application/pdf",
   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.script": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation": [
   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
   "application/pdf",
   "text/plain"
  ]
 }
}
```

As you can see, there are currently no export formats defined for `application/vnd.google-apps.map`. Given that Google My Maps does support exporting to KMZ/KML, I think ideally the Google Drive API would as well. You can file a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Drive).

Comment: Thanks Eric. [Issue 4693](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4693)

Comment: Thanks Eric, could you please update the link to the feature request?